# Http guzzle request with no response

Tags: localhost, webserver, lumen, guzzle

In my Lumen project, I needed to use the Guzzle client to send requests from the server side to create acces tokens and provide them to the correctly authentified users.
The problem is that whenener I send a guzzlehttp request I get no response, using Postmen to send them and request stops just because of the time out.

I tried  simple example in the web.php file:

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    //return $app->version();
    $http= new Client();
    return json_decode($http->get('localhost:8088/user'));

});
```

and when I excute it using the Lumen integrated server I get this:
[no end request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiMWf.png)

Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I searched about the problem, someone told me that Those requests don't work in the local server, so I tried Xampp and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It would be nice if you would mark your own answer as accepted, so that other users can benefit from it too.