# Guzzle in laravel keeps loading, not returning values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, guzzle

Im using Laravel passport for API authentication. I have two routes 
      /api/login
and
      /oauth/token

Since I cannot hardcode my client id and the login receives from JS and the params and client id is hardcoded inside a login method(laravel), Im trying to post the values using Guzzle (6.0) to oauth/token (POST requests).

I followed a youtube video and there it works but not mine. Iam using 5.6, not sure which version was in the video. Could someone help?

Below is the Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGh0cKEVXPI&t=838s

Below is the code

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $http->post(URI, '/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => 'bar',
        'password' => 'xxxxxx',
        'client_id' => 2,
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_secret' => '00000000000000000'
    ]
]);

return $request;
```

Comment: can I have Guzzle request code here?

Comment: Updated @VasimVanzara.. could you help?

Comment: check your log file is there any error? because above is perfect call.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48966994/8531813) resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the response only returning guzzle `$request` initalization so add `getBody()`

```
   $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $http->post(URI, '/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'username' => 'bar',
            'password' => 'xxxxxx',
            'client_id' => 2,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_secret' => '00000000000000000'
        ]
    ]);

    return $request->getBody();
```

Comment: I believe that the return should be `(string) $request->getBody();`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to request in build-in server.
So You try two servers to send the request. 
It will be working.

Like **localhost:8000** and **localhost:9000** server

Use this command

**php artisan serve**

**php artisan serve --port=9000**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the status first to make sure that everything is okay by using

```
$request->getStatusCode();
```

You can get your response by

```
$request->getBody();
```

you can see also full documentation of using GuzzulHttp from Here 
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/